# How to close a file using Directory.EnumerateFiles to loop through files C#

Tags: c#, directory

Ive searched high and low and cant find anything specific, maybe because my knowledge is limited.

I am looping through files and doing "stuff" with it :

```
foreach (var file in Directory.EnumerateFiles(scannedFilesLocation, "*.tif"))
{               
    fileName = Path.GetFileName(file.ToString());

    var tifImage = Image.FromFile(file.ToString());
    // var imageContent = ImageHelper.ImageToByteArray(tifImage);
    var tiffArray = File.ReadAllBytes(file);
    string contentType = "";

    new FileExtensionContentTypeProvider().TryGetContentType(fileName, out contentType);

    var newScannedDocument = new AddDocumentToFileStore();

    newScannedDocument.DocumentName = fileName;
    newScannedDocument.ContentType = contentType;
    newScannedDocument.Content = tiffArray;
    newScannedDocument.Meta.Add("FileName", fileName);

    newScannedDocumentList.Add(newScannedDocument);
}
```

At the end of the loop, I want to move or delete the file, but when I use `File.Delete(...)` I get an error stating that the file is in use - Which I completely understand, but how do I close this specific file to perform this `Delete` ?

Thanks for any help!

Comment: That depends on "Things being done here". Please post a [mcve].

Comment: I will post all the code, hope it helps

Comment: It seems you don't actually need `tifImage`. You can follow the advice in the answer, that's correct. You could also just remove that line, that would solve your problem, too.

Comment: 100% correct! I was initially using it, seems I forgot to remove it. Thanks for pointing it out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Edit:
It seems like this post changed from the way I first read it a minute ago.

This might work:

```
// destroy the reference
tifImage.Dispose();
```

Or

```
using (Image image = Image.FromFile(fileName))
{
   // do your processing
}
```

I think that works, from very used memory above my neck.

Another thing you might could try is make a copy of the file and do your 'stuff'.

```
System.IO.File.Copy(source, target); // (I think that is right, I don't have VS open at the moment).
```

This way your original never got a handle opened, and if your copy is in a temp location, and for whatever reason you are unable to delete the copy during the processing of your file, delete it periodically.

Maybe that helps, or you can do your deletes later in another process.

Comment: I did update my post afterward, my apologies, as I initially thought the code inside my foreach was not relevant, but clearly it was. Does the code I posted help ?

Comment: I tried `tifImage = null;` but still says that the file is being used by another process. Is this possibly a wrong way of looping through files? Is the a "better" way? I dont mind changing the way it works, as long as it follows any best practices.

Comment: That was just a guess. Sorry, I am tired at the moment. I will make a note 'doesn't work.'

Try the make a copy might be your best bet.

Comment: I just updated my answer, tifImage.Dispose() might work.

Comment: Actually your `using` statement did the job! Thanks! I am aware that when using `using` it disposes of the image after its done, didnt think about this. Thanks again!

Comment: You are welcome, I have a similar issue in one of my projects, I just always click 'Save As', because Save has the same bug you just described. I may go fix it now.

Comment: `tifImage.Dispose()` worked as well! Even less code :) Thank you man! Cant believe Ive sat here for 2 hours on something so small... Your awesome!